# Unreachable, existing variable

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm new at as3, maybe thats the reason why i don't understand, why the `setInterval` causes an error.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.utils.setInterval;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        [Bindable]
        public var MyInt:int = 500;

        setInterval(function():void{ ++MyInt; },1000);

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

I have a label where the value of `MyInt` gets visible, the bind works perfect, i've tested it several ways, and i i create a button it grows the number, but if i use the `setInterval` function i get an error: `Access of undefined property myInt`.

Why? What does cause this? Please explain it, so I can avoid errors like this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about Flex, but I think the problem is that this code:

```
setInterval(function():void{ ++MyInt; },1000);
```

Is run like if it was placed in a class definition, outside any function. That makes the code a static initializer. That is, it's run in a static context, which means it has no access to any instance, since no instance has yet been created when the code runs.

This seems to prove it:

```
public static var MyInt:int = 500;

setInterval(function():void { ++MyInt; trace(MyInt); },1000);
```

With `static`, the code works fine.

You probably don't want `MyInt` to be static, though. So you should put the `setInterval` call within an instance method. Assuming `init` is called from the `mx:Application` `initialize` callback, this should work fine:

```
    [Bindable]
    public var MyInt:int = 500;

    private function init():void {
        setInterval(function():void { ++MyInt; trace(MyInt); },1000);
    }
```

Comment: My bad with the function closure, I unconsciously placed the setinterval code in a init function when running so I did not notice. I deleted my answer